# Android Set/Get Get() returns null in Android

Tags: android

I've 3 activities. First activity sets `id`, activity second is `menu` and activity third to show `id`.

But, third activity shows `null` id. Why?

**a.class**:

```
package a.b.c.model;
public class Profil {   
    private String pid;
    public String getpId() {
        return pid;
    }
    public void setpId(String id) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }
}
```

**b.class**:

```
package a.b.c;
import a.b.c.model;
public class bextends Activity {
    Profil p = new Profil();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);
        p.setpId("TEST");
    }
}
```

**c.class**:

```
package a.b.c;
import a.b.c.model;
public class c extends Activity {
    Profil p = new Profil();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c);
        final TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pid);
        tex.setText(p.getpId());
    }
}
```

**d.class**

```
package a.b.c.model;
public class d extends Activity {   
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.d);;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
activity class
b -> d -> c

Comment: activity b and c holds different **Profil** objects. how can you get the value from first object using the newly created second one?

Comment: check my updated answer, just copy it and try to execute. Hope it will give your expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your b.class your creating a new object and setting the value to the object means it is a local object and you can use with in the class reference only. In your c.class when ever your crating a new object means it is freshly created i.e it don't have any values in it.

When ever you created an object like below means, it always empty and it having only null values in it.

```
       Profil p = new Profil();
```

So coming to your solution, you can achieve it by many ways based on your specifications / requirements /scope

one way is make your classes like below

a.class

```
package a.b.c.model;
public class Profil implements Serializable {   

        /**  auto generated serial version id
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String pid;
    public String getpId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setpId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

b.class

```
package a.b.c;
import a.b.c.model;
public class bextends Activity {
    Profil p = new Profil();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.b);
        p.setpId("TEST");
}
```

after some button action click (navigating from b to c) you can send your Serialized Profile object to B class to C and then you can use it

your intent should be like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, D.class);
i.putExtra("sampleObject", p);
startActivity(i);
```

In your 'D' activity you need to get the object which your sending form activity b.

d.class

```
package a.b.c.model;
public class d extends Activity {   

    Profil p = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.d);

         p = (Profil)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");
    }
}
```

your intent should be like this (D activity to C activity)

```
// this you can write in your navigation part probably in a button click
Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
i.putExtra("sampleObject", p);
startActivity(i);
```

After receiving object when ever your navigating from activity 'D' to activity 'C' you need to pass the updated object in the same way

Then your C class should be like this

C.class

```
package a.b.c;
import a.b.c.model;
public class c extends Activity {
    Profil p = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.c);

         p = (Profil)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");

        final TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pid);
        tex.setText(p.getpId());
    }
}
```

That's it :) now you can use the updated Profile object in your C class as well..

Note:: As i told earlier this is a basic approach.. there is too many alternative approaches will do the same operation better than this

Comment: c.class is third activity, and a.class is first activity ?

Comment: a.class is not an activity, b.class is first activity and c.class is second activity.  you can set the value in b.class and pass the complete object to c.class through intent.. i updated entire logic in my answer.

Comment: Use `Parcelable` [instead of `Serializable`](http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/)

Answer (score 2):

If you intend `pid` to be global to the `Profil` class, you should make the `pid` variable static. A static variable belongs to the class itself, and not the instance of said class.

So our fix would look as simple as `private static String pid;`, and making our getters and setters static as well.

If you wish for each `Profil` to be able to have its own `pid`, then you'll need to pass the correct instance of `Profil` to where it is needed. A new instance of a class is generally always created with the `new` keyword. So remember, if we see `new` there's a new instance, and any non static variables are not kept and are separate from other instances.

Answer (score 1):

In `c.class`, `p` is a new object with `pid == null`. You need to pass it from `b` to `c` through a [`Bundle.`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)